# Why does Outbound Email refuse to re-send mailing to contacts?

Tags: outbound-email

I'm testing outbound email functionality for my project. I created a new mailing and added address book and Distribution list and tried to test it. But I have a few issues that I need to confirm:

1. I'm able to send mail to all contacts in distribution list 1st time by clicking on "Send Mail". But if I want to send mail again it says there are 0 contacts to send mail. So why can't I send same mail again?
2. I changed the Page in "Mailing" by selecting new page but it still says 0 mails to send as I already sent it 1st time with old page. Is it that every time for sending mail I have to create new Mailing and existing mailing can be used only once?

If I'm wrong, please guide me how exactly Outbound Email works.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure others can give a more detailed answer but I think that behaviour is by design - you need a new distribution list.

Ultimately OE is telling you "I've sent the mail to everyone in the distribution list, there's no-one left to send it to".

Comment: I don't know if any further clarification is needed. You're exactly right -- it's done to prevent you from accidentally spamming your Contacts. You're not supposed to Send the Mailing until it's finalized and you're sure you want to send it out (it even has you confirm it!). Before that time, you should use Test Mailing to make sure the e-mails look as they should and that your content is ready to be presented to you Contacts.